# Oracle Blob as img src in PHP not shown

Tags: php, oracle

I want to show a profile image which saved into oracle database 19c as blob data type.

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT PHOTOGRAPH FROM MEMBER_VIEW WHERE UPPER(MEMBERSHIPNO)=UPPER('".$memberid."')";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_execute($stid);

$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

if (!$row) {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
} else {
    $img = $row['PHOTOGRAPH'];
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    print $img;
}




?>


<img src="image.php" />
```

after running this code only blank page with black background show instead  of image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b6KU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
?>


<img src="image.php" />
```

You don't want any extra space or anything that's not the payload of the image itself.

Comment: afterr removing  <img src="image.php" /> this line of code ,still image not show .